# use List Foreach instead of for() Java

Tags: java, list, foreach

I'm currently learning Java and I'm interested in learning how to use the list foreach method rather than using a manually constructed for loop. I suspect they can perform the same.

My current code looks like this:

```
while(!this.cards.isEmpty()) {
    for(int i = 0; i < this.table.GetPlayerCount()  && !this.cards.isEmpty(); i++) {
    DealOneCardToPlayer(this.table.players.get(i) ,this.cards.get(0));
    this.cards.remove(0);
    }
}
```

I suspect that there is a way to use something like this:

```
this.cards.foreach() { do suff }
```

but I haven't quite been able to nail down the syntax... can someone give me a quick hand?

Comment: That extra condition in your `for(...)` means that this is not a simple `for` loop. If you're trying to learn how to use `forEach`, this is not the best example to learn with.

Comment: You don't *really* need to remove cards in the loop, though. If you use `this.cards.iterator()` instead, you can simply get the next card, without removing them (and then you can call `this.cards.clear()` afterwards, if you want).

Comment: well, I am attempting to learn how to model the 'real world' right - so when a dealer is dealing cards from a 'deck' which is what this loop is doing. when a card is dealt to a player it is 'removed' from the 'deck'. I think I would like to retain that - The code is working - I was just looking for the more concise way of expressing it and I thought foreach was it. @user902383 why do you say that you don't think I can use a foreach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it by iterating over the indexes of the cards:

```
IntStream.range(0, this.cards.size()).forEach(idx -> {
    DealOneCardToPlayer(
        this.table.players.get(idx % this.table.GetPlayerCount()),
        this.cards.get(idx));
});
```

Although this doesn't remove the cards as you go; if you really need `this.cards` to be empty after:

```
this.cards.clear();
```

---

If you want to limit the number of cards dealt out (e.g. you want to deal N cards to each player), the easiest way is to extract a sublist, and then just apply the same method above:

```
List<Card> cardsToDeal = this.cards.subList(0, numCardsToDeal);
IntStream.range(0, cardsToDeal.size()).forEach(idx -> {
    DealOneCardToPlayer(
        this.table.players.get(idx % this.table.GetPlayerCount()),
        cardsToDeal.get(idx));
});
cardsToDeal.clear();
```

Comment: well yes - i do need the 'deck' of cards to have had the cards that were 'dealt' to be removed. However while this currently doesn't handle dealing fewer cards than the 'deck' has, it will eventually. So I'm not sure this.cards.clear(); would be the right move for that... thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand the problem you think there is - this deals as many cards as there are cards (assuming cards isn't being modified in another thread at the same time). So, if you want to "remove" them from the deck, iterating them and then clearing the deck has the same effect as removing each card as you iterate them.

Comment: right - currently the iterator removes ALL the cards from the deck. However in the future, once I code it, it will deal a set number of cards to each player (determined by a different method). There will be cards left in the deck after those cards are dealt. Currently this simply deals every card in the deck and that's it.

Comment: Then do `IntStream.range(0, numPlayers * numCardsPerPlayer)`, and `this.cards.subList(0, numPlayers * numCardsPerPlayer).clear()`. Or, `List<Card> subCards = this.cards.subList(0, numPlayers * numCardsPerPlayer)`, and then replace all references to `this.cards` with `subCards`. (Of course, you also need to ensure that `numPlayers * numCardsPerPlayer <= this.cards.size()`).

Comment: What do I need to import to use InStream?

Comment: [In**t**Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html). (As in, stream of integers)

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about Java 8's Function API (and lambdas).

Essentially lambdas are a shorthand brethren to functions/methods, they have inputs and potentially return values. For the `#forEach`, it requests that you provide a function which accepts a `T` (Your list type), and returns nothing. This is known as a `Consumer`. The method then takes the `Consumer` you gave it, and calls it for each element on your list.

For equivalency, these are essentially the same thing as far as you're concerned when developing:

```
void someConsumerMethod(Card c) {
    //lambda code block
}


(Card c) -> //lambda code block


this::someConsumerMethod //direct reference to the first method
```

An example would be:

```
this.cards.forEach(c -> {
    System.out.println(c); //fully expanded
});
this.cards.forEach(c -> System.out.println(c)); //shorthand / one-liner
//or, since println already matches a Consumer<Object>, we can method reference it!
this.cards.forEach(System.out::println);
```

As for adapting your example, I wouldn't recommend modifying a collection while you iterate it (at least, not without using `Iterator#remove`). Andy Turner's answer already shows you how to use an application of `IntStream` to iterate the indexes you want.

Comment: yes I think Lambdas is what I was interested in. I'll give this a shot soon and see what I come up with.. Thanks Rogue.

Comment: You should brush up on the function api as well, as they're quite involved for the "receiving" end of lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is lambda expressions. The forEach method takes a functional interface (an interface with one abstract method), meaning it can be used as follows:

```
  List<String> myList;
  myList.forEach((String s) -> System.out.println(s));
```

Source: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to use new Java 8 streams with your List.

So the syntax is like:

```
this.cards.stream().forEach(card -> {// do something here});
```

You can call **stream()** to access the method *forEach()*.

Or directly with your List:

```
this.cards.forEach(...);
```

In my example I use the new Java 8 arrow functions that is a convenient way to avoids the boiler plate of the anonymous class (much an evolution).

You can pass a method to the *forEach()*:

```
this.cards.stream().forEach(doSomethingWithMyCard);
```

Comment: A list (any `Iterable` even) implements `forEach` directly, there is no need to use `stream().forEach(...)`.

Comment: in fact, Iterable contains the method, and `Map` has a `#forEach` as well which is a `BiConsumer<K, V>`

Answer (score 0):

You may keep track of the current player index, and iterate over the cards pack, to distribute it entirely :

```
int playerIndex = 0;

for(Card card : cards){

  DealOneCardToPlayer(this.table.players.get(playerIndex) , card);

  if(playerIndex == this.table.GetPlayerCount()-1)
    playerIndex = 0;
  else
    playerIndex = playerIndex + 1;


}
```

If you only want to distribute one card per player, replace

```
  if(playerIndex == this.table.GetPlayerCount()-1)
    playerIndex = 0;
  else
    playerIndex = playerIndex + 1;
```

With :

```
  if(playerIndex == this.table.GetPlayerCount()-1)
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not really suitable to be converted to a `forEach` call because you have all those extra conditions in there and stuff. You are also modifying the list in the for loop. Because of these reasons, you better stick with a for loop.

A `forEach` call can be used when you want to mutate the objects in a list, or you just want to access each item in the list.

The syntax looks like this:

```
list.forEach(item -> <insert the stuff you want to do to the item here>);
```

Here are some examples showing how to use `forEach`. I also provided the equivalent for loop:

```
// forEach
list.forEach(item -> item.setSomeProperty(1));
// for loop
for (int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++) {
    list.get(i).setSomeProperty(1);
}

// forEach
list.forEach(item -> item.doStuff());
// for loop
for (int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++) {
    list.get(i).doStuff()
}

// forEach
list.forEach(item -> System.out.println(item));
// for loop
for (int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

Hopefully you can understand the syntax by looking at the above examples.

Note that the last example can be simplified to:

```
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

We're basically telling it to call `System.out::println` on each item.